# Is it this mapping a bijection, surjection, bijection? If it's a bijection give it's inverse, if it's only an injection give it's partial inverse.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\varphi_{10} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, n\rightarrow \{6n+1 ($if n is even$), 6n-1$ if n is odd}

Well, I've calculated it, which gives that $1 \rightarrow 5$, $2 \rightarrow 13$, $3 \rightarrow 17$, $4 \rightarrow 25$, $5 \rightarrow 29$, $6 \rightarrow 37$, $7 \rightarrow 41...$

I think that this is surjective, because for $ \rho: A \rightarrow B, (\forall b \in B)(\exists a \in A)(a \rho = b) $ I assume that this is true.

And it's injective if $(\forall a_{1},a_{2} \in A)(a_{1} \rho = a_{2} \rho \rightarrow a_{1}=a_{2})$
 so it has to be an injection but in which way can I show it exactly? And how can I get an inverse for it?

Comment: At least I'm sure that this is injective, but I'm not sure that this is surjective also, because not every $\mathbb{N}$ numbers are in the $B$set

Comment: It is not surjective. The values of $\phi_{10}$ are all odd integers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

For injectivity:

Consider two points $n_1\neq n_2$ and imply $\varphi_{10}(n_1)\neq \varphi_{10}(n_2)$. You have to consider three cases:
First, $n_1$ and $n_2$ are even. Next, $n_1$ is even and $n_2$ is odd. Finally, $n_1$ and $n_2$ are odd.

For not surjectivity:

You can see that $\varphi_{10}(n)\geq 6n-1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

For the partial inverse:

The first step is to understand the image $\varphi_{10}(\mathbb N)$. For an even number $n$, you find a number $k$ such that $n=2k$ and for an odd number $n$, you find a number $k$ such that $n=2k+1$. Hence, you should consider $\varphi_{10}(2k)$ and $\varphi_{10}(2k+1)$. Then you can see how to characterize a number $m\in \varphi_{10}(\mathbb N)$ depending on $k$ and find the partial inverse function.

Comment: and how can I restrict it to get a partial inverse?

Comment: I added a hint in my answer.